# cfmakeraw implicit declaration error

Tags: c, implicit-declaration

I am writing multithread application (as homework). One of those threads is dedicated for reading keyboard presses, so using terminal in raw mode. But I keep getting error

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘cfmakeraw’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     cfmakeraw(&tio);
```

even though I have **unistd.h** and **termios.h** included.

I am programming on Linux (xubuntu 16.04) using gcc 5.4.0 with -std=c99 flag. The code looks something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "prg_serial_nonblock.h"

void set_raw(_Bool set);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // terminal raw mode
    set_raw(true);

    // ... some thread magic ...

    set_raw(false);
    printf("\n");
}

void set_raw(_Bool set) {
    static struct termios tio, tioOld;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tio);

    if (set) { // put the terminal to raw
        tioOld = tio; //backup
        cfmakeraw(&tio);
        tio.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // assure echo is disabled
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tio);
    }
    else {      // set the previous settingsreset
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tioOld);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [manpage](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/cfmakeraw.3.en.html) says,

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see [feature_test_macros(7)](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/feature_test_macros.7.en.html)):
>
> **cfsetspeed**(), **cfmakeraw**():
>   Since glibc 2.19:
>   `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`
>   Glibc 2.19 and earlier:
>   `_BSD_SOURCE`

So you should either add `-D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE` to the command-line, or add `#define _BSD_SOURCE` and `#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE` before any system `#include`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!