# POSIX read() call remains blocked forever regardless of what's set in VTIME

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, embedded, posix

I need to configure the UART settings such that the `read()` call remains blocked until a certain time before it's unblocked again if it didn't receive any data within the timeout. So if the timeout is 5 seconds, it remains blocked till 5 seconds max if it doesn't receive any byte and then unblocks...

I tried using `VMIN` which should block the `read()` call until no character is read within the time allowed, after which the call to `read()` returns 0, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me: the `read()` call remains blocked forever and as soon as I enter stuff in a minicom serial session, `read()` unblocks and then goes back to getting blocked again.

I'm not sure if it's taking into account `VTIME` setting, or maybe I'm misconfiguring it.

Rather, would `select()` with a timeout be a better approach?

```
#define SERIAL_PORT     "/dev/ttyUSB4" 

pthread_t td;
int fd;

int SerialOpen()
{   
    struct termios term;
    
    fd = open(SERIAL_PORT, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror ("failed to open");
        return -1;
    }
    
    bzero(&term, sizeof(term));
    cfmakeraw(&term);
    
    term.c_cflag |= CREAD;
    tcgetattr(fd, &term);
    
    term.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;
    term.c_iflag &= ~INLCR;
    term.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;

    term.c_oflag &= ~OCRNL;
    term.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;
    term.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    term.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    term.c_lflag &= ~IEXTEN;
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ECHOE|ECHOK|ECHONL|ECHOCTL|ECHOPRT|ECHOKE);
    
    cfsetspeed(term, B115200);      // set baud rate
    term.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    term.c_cflag |= CS8;
    
    // disable flow control
    term.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;           
    term.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF);
    
    term.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;       // no parity
    
    term.c_cc[VTIME] = 50;    // Wait for up to 5s (50 deciseconds), returning as soon as any data is received.
    term.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

    if ( (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &term)) < 0)
    {
        perror ("Failed to set attr");
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}


void *Rx(void *arg)
{
    char buff[100] = {0};
    
    while(1)
    {
        int sz = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff)); // block until VTIME times out
        if (sz < 0)
        {
            perror ("Read failed");
        }
        printf ("Received bytes %d:  %s\n", sz, buff);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int ret = SerialOpen();
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (pthread_create(&td, NULL, Rx, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Fail to create thread!\n");
    }
    
    pthread_join(td, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have `bzero`, `cfmakeraw`, and `term.c_cflag |= CREAD` _before_ doing `tcgetattr(fd,&term)`. So, all that will be blown away by the `tcgetattr` call.

Comment: I might do: `c_cflag &= ~CSIZE` before doing `c_cflag |= CS8`

Comment: I might also add: `c_cflag |= CLOCAL`

Comment: After applying some/all of the above, with your `VMIN = 0` and `VTIME = 50`, you _should_ get timeout after 5 seconds, or immediate return on first/any char. If not, remote device may not be sending data. You can set most of this with `minicom`'s config and test whether the remote device is responding. The remote _may_ need to have the control lines (e.g. RTS/CTS) either tied low/high or have S/W set them. (i.e. the device _needs_ valid control lines, regardless of the `CRTSCTS` settings).

Comment: Even if nothing is being sent from minicom, the read call should timeout based on VTIME no?

Comment: As I said, it _should_ timeout, assuming you've fixed the other errata I mentioned. Try `VTIME = 0` to start--the only penalty you pay for is a bit more polling. What is the device on the other end (e.g. `FTDI`, etc.)?

Comment: You mean `VTIME=0, VMIN=0`? this should make `read` return rightaway yes? doesn't work. It's one of those USB to RS232 cables

Comment: I have some realworld/practical experience with USB to UART cables. They can be tricky. I'd review the datasheet and check the pin diagram. Also, it could be the end device as well. Because of the USB, the driver may not behave like a straight RS232 cable. It's difficult to set VTIME in `minicom`

Comment: Aaah. Do you think I could make use of `select` with a specified timeout and then proceed to `read` once `select` returns which is either there's data to be read or the timer timed out? I tried with `stdin` and it works fine. Not sure if that'd work the same with serial port which uses file descriptor

Comment: What is your build environment?  I can't compile the code you posted!  You have not posted a MRE. Even adding required **#include** statements, the compile ***fails*** on `cfsetspeed(term, B115200);`  What code are you actually executing?

Comment: I'm using some custom Linux. Try adding `#define _BSD_SOURCE` & `#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE` before any includes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43663465/12497236

Comment: FYI after making appropriate corrections as previously mentioned, the code executes as expected.

Comment: Read my previous/first comment very carefully.  **Your code has a typo/bug.**  Adding some macros is not going to compensate for your typo/bug.  The compile of your posted code still fails.

Comment: Seems like you have not learned anything since [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68687325/vtime-and-vmin-dont-seem-to-change-the-blocking-behaviour-of-the-posix-read-c) from five weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* Prefaced by the top comments.

Be sure you're applying the fixes I suggested in the comments above.

`select` may have the same issues as `VMIN/VTIME`. `select` operates at a level *after* the TTY layer [which is where `VMIN/VTIME` operate]. At a lower level is the USB driver. If the TTY layer isn't set up correctly, `select` may have the same issues as `read` (i.e. probably *not* the issue). Although, you might do: `open(/dev/whatever,O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)`

But, I suspect that the issue is at a more fundamental/lower level. I think the USB layer/level is part of the problem.

USB-to-RS232 cables are tricky. The *cable* may *need* active H/W flow control enabled to operate. So, just disabling H/W flow control via (e.g.) clearing `CRTSCTS` may not work too well.

*Double check:* Are you sure that you are getting all the way through the configuration/initialization of the device. Could the `open` be hanging? You could add debug `printf` statements throughout the code [easier than using `gdb` for this].

What is the specific manufacturer and device for the USB cable? What is the specific manufacturer/model of the end/UART device? Although the standard/generic USB serial driver (e.g. `usbserial`) *should* work, some vendors need a specific driver (e.g. `FTDI` has its own USB level driver). So, you may need to consult the manufacturer's website/datasheet for the *specific* devices in question.

Also, sometimes a USB cable shows up on two different `/dev/tty*` devices. You may have the wrong one. You may need `ttyS*` instead of `ttyUSB*` or the device *can* show up as (e.g.) `ttyACM*` !!! This *can* occur even if `ttyS*` or `ttyUSB*` are [also] present.

Look at:

1. `ls -l /dev`
2. `/proc/devices`
3. `/sys/devices`
4. `lsmod`
5. `lsusb`
6. `lspci`
7. `dmesg` [and, maybe, syslog output]

Did you [or the system] `modprobe usbserial`?

Specifically, the `dmesg` output should say which `tty*` the device is connected to.

Some resources (from a "all the words" websearch on `linux /dev USB uart cable`):

1. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-linux-serial-ports-with-setserial/
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81754/how-to-match-a-ttyusbx-device-to-a-usb-serial-device

Comment: Thanks for the response. I check the return value of functions including `open`, `read` as specified in the snippet. Anything else I should be checking as well?. And I can certainly send stuff from Minicom and be able to receive on the device fine, so I reckon the serial port used is fine. For the specific details on the cable itself, I'd have to check.

Comment: Please go over my comments again and the suggested remedies there and in my answer. Specifically, I see _bugs_ in the `termios` setup in your code, relative to code I have for such setup [that works]. See the `CSIZE` addition. Look at `dmesg` output. Note that if you have (e.g.) `ttyUSB*` opening it [successfully] does _not_ necessarily mean it is the correct device to use. It could be one of the others I mentioned. Retrace your steps and reverify each one. What about _enabling_ H/W flow control?

Comment: I've asked a few times for vendor/device information but you've not provided it. Based on your comments, you're assuming the issue must be where _you_ think it is (e.g. `VTIME` and/or `select`) and banging harder there will fix the issue. Take a step back and (re)examine other areas. You may assume, but you should also verify ...

Comment: Yes, I now invoke `tcgetattr` right after `open` after which the rest of stuff happens `bzero`, `term.c_cflag |= (CREAD | CLOCAL);`, etc. Also `term->c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;` is before `term->c_cflag |= CS8;`. And about the ttyUSB*, if I could receive and send stuff through it, wouldn't that indicate that this is the correct device node used for the UART communication? just trying to clarify the picture here. I'd try enabling H/W flow control tomorrow when I'm near my work station

Comment: What does `dmesg` say? It is the _first_ line of defense. It is the first thing each of the links I've found mention. As I said, _try_ the other devices [if they exist]. It isn't logical, but some USB tty devices are finicky

Comment: not quite seeing any obvious suspect in dmesg. Also with `select`, the timeout works fine. it should hopefully be a matter of invoking `read()` after to read the serial data. Would have to test it though

Comment: @xyf *"Yes, I now invoke `tcgetattr` right after `open` after which the rest of stuff happens `bzero`, ..."*  -- **Wrong!**  Calling **bzero()** negates the entire purpose of calling **tcgetattr()**.  Study [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html)

Comment: Low-quality answer. (1) The code fixes are not contained within the answer. Requires access to comments that may be removed in the future, which would render the "answer" incomplete.  (2) Rest of "answer" focuses on the name of the device, which is unlikely to be the issue, since the OP has been using this setup for over 5 weeks, and has posted other related questions.  The naming of USB tty devices is (usually) consistent, and is only confusing if you ignore or don't understand what is the device end of the USB cable,